# Find number of connections between nodes in igraph network in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have created an undirected igraph with the following edges
`A--A`,`A--B`,`B--A`,`C--D`,`A--C`and`A--B`

```
library(igraph)
my_data = data.frame(id1=c("A","A","B","C","A","A"),id2=c("A","B","A","D","C","B"))
g = graph.data.frame(my_data,directed=F)
```

I want an output such that it lists all the unique edges and count of each edge. Below is a sample based on above graph.

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
   A       A       1
   A       B       3
   A       C       1
   C       D       1
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @symbolrush - found a workaround. please the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out. Used the below code to get the output.

```
library(igraph)
require(splitstackshape)
require(data.table)

my_data = data.frame(id1=c("A","B","C","A","A"),id2=c("B","A","D","C","B"))
g = graph.data.frame(my_data,directed=F)

edge=as_ids(E(g))
edge=as.data.frame(edge)
split = as.data.table(cSplit(edge,"edge","|"))
split[,':='(dummy=1,
            key = paste(edge_1,edge_2,sep="_"))]
split = unique(split[,.(edge_1,edge_2,sum(dummy)),by=key])[,2:4,with=F]
split

# A B 3
# C D 1
# A C 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like,

```
table(vapply(paste(my_data$id1, my_data$id2), function(i) paste(sort(strsplit(i, ' ')[[1]]), collapse=' '), ' '))

#A A A B A C C D 
#  1   3   1   1
```